# First Derivative Question

Tags: calculus

I came across a problem in my math textbook, illustrated here:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight into the solution. I am confused because a+b are wrong since it is f'(x) that is decreasing/increasing respectively, not f(x). C is wrong since 0 appears to be the critical number of f'(x) thus excluding it from the possible increasing/decreasing domain as it would have a slope of 0. D is not necessarily true, as corners on f'(x) do not reflect differentiability of f(x); consider x|x| where its derivative has a corner, yet f(x) is differentiable at all points. E is not true, as a minimum is defined by f'(x) moving from - to +.

Thus, i'm confused as to what answer is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your teacher might have made a mistake on the closure, is all.  You might get extra credit for annoying them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3) is correct: $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[-2,0]$.

Note that the graph is of $f'(x)$, not $f(x)$.

The fact that $f'(0)=0$ does not change our conclusion. Remember that the assumptions for the mean value theorem concern the derivative *in the open interval*, and the values of the derivative at the endpoints are irrelevant for the theorem. The derivative of $f$ is positive in $(-2,0)$ and $f$ is continuous on $[-2,0]$ (since the derivative is defined there), thus $f$ is increasing on $[-2,-0]$.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. But on this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see your question was answered.

Comment: Yup! However, the 15 minute mark is restricting my up-vote and acceptance. I'll make sure to accept it and upvote it as soon as the timer expires.

Comment: That's fine. Remember to upvote and/or accept any other good answers, if they come.

Comment: It appears that I can't up vote unless I have greater than 15 reputation. However, I did accept the answer.